# How to use SetElementValue on XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

This is the sample of my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SearchHistory>
    <Search>
        <title>Text 1</title>
        <count>0</count>
    </Search>
    <Search>
        <title>Text 2</title>
        <count>0</count>
    </Search>
</SearchHistory>
```

And I want to change the value of **count** of Text 1

this is what i tried:

```
xdoc.Descendants("Search")
    .Where(x => x.Element("title").Value == tbSearch.Text)
    .Single().SetElementValue("count", curCount);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Unless none of your `<title>` elements' values match `tbSearch.Text`, this should behave as you expect.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi they match... if i put wrong value on tbSearch.Text it throw me exception... I don't get any error, its just not change the count value

Comment: @Loclip, how do you verify the count value has changed or not?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I put one manually exactly before the above code just to ensure that it change

Comment: @CuongLe I give the value of tbSearch.Text, its not the problem

Comment: are you positive the value of `curCount` is not also `1`?

Comment: @Stefano, as I said in a comment under Smartis's answer, you do not have to match the `<count>` element because `SetElementValue()` sets the value of the child element whose name you specify, not of the element it's called on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Save the `XDocument` when you have made changes

```
xDoc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: Why the DownVote? I have tried his code and with properly call to Save the Value is changed in the file....

Comment: I don't know why they downvoted... this is actually the only answer worked :D

Answer (score 0):

```
xdoc.Descendants("Search")
    .Where(x => x.Element("title").Value == tbSearch.Text)
    .Single()
    .Descendants("count")
    .Single()
    .Value = "1";
```

Comment: This will only change the value at runtime, if you are working from an XML file you need to rewrite your `XDocument`